# Return value from the prototype function in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my function, I'm trying to return a value.

```
var operations = function() {

    this.selectedQueryBy = function() {            
          return jQuery('input[type="radio"][name="selectRadio"]:checked').attr("id")
   },
   this.submitForm = function() {
          jQuery('.btns').hide();
          var queryBy = this.selectedQueryBy;
    }
}
```

Im trying to get the value of "selectedqueryby" which is already defined in the function. It returns the whole function instead of the radio button. Is the calling way correct?

Please let me know where Im doing wrong.

I'll call the submitForm event on clicking a button.

Comment: Try `this.selectedQueryBy()`

Comment: @Mohammad. Correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add parentheses to call the function:

```
var queryBy = this.selectedQueryBy();
                               // ^^
```

Otherwise you're just referring to the function itself instead of calling it.

Comment: Right. Any other better way than my calling ?